# Gray screen after login Fedora 27 / Wayland or Xorg

Tags: fedora, boot, login

After shutdown, Fedora 27 boots to login mode, after loggng in freezes at gray screen. I can go into the shell, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and everything seems to be fine. I've tried Wayland and XOrg, I even uncommented `usewayland=false` in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: So, it's not really freezing but you've got nothing on your x-windows.  What did you install as desktop?

Comment: Issue `sudo journalctl -b` to see what's happening. It may show what is causing the issue.